# Redirect Virtual Domain to Another Server

Tags: apache2

Is it possible to forward a virtual domain on my primary Webserver (Running Ubuntu 20.04/Apache2) to an internal Webserver that is running the same setup, except it doesn't have a domain associated with it (yet, I can set up one if needed).

I want to forward a domain I own to the other server (a Raspberry Pi 4 running a weather station).

I have tried to set up RYSNC over SSH, but no matter what guide I follow, it always asks for a password, so I have pretty much given up on that.

Running Ubuntu 20.04
Server version: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2020-08-12T19:46:17

I managed to get the domain forwarding to the other Apache server, except the address shows the IP address of the PI running the weather software. Could I make the webserver on server2 use a different port, with a domain name and then forward from server1 to server2 with the specific port and have it do name resolution?

Thanks!

Comment: I feel this is valid case for a reverse proxy. Try searching on this site for reverse proxy configuration, there is a plenty of answers.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov Thanks, I will start looking up about Reverse Proxy and see what I can find, thanks.